# Django - How to pass data to new view (not in url)

Tags: python, django, session

How can I pass/redirect few variables to a new view but I want to make it under the scene, not in URL.

models.py

```
class Parings_3(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
p1 = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=ARMIES_CHOICE)
p2 = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=ARMIES_CHOICE)
p3 = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=ARMIES_CHOICE)
op1 = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=ARMIES_CHOICE)
op2 = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=ARMIES_CHOICE)
op3 = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=ARMIES_CHOICE)
p11 = models.IntegerField()
p12 = models.IntegerField()
p13 = models.IntegerField()
p21 = models.IntegerField()
p22 = models.IntegerField()
p23 = models.IntegerField()
p31 = models.IntegerField()
p32 = models.IntegerField()
p33 = models.IntegerField()
date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

forms.py

```
class ParingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ParingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for i in ["p11", "p12", "p13", "p21", "p22", "p23", "p31", "p32", "p33"]:
        self.fields[i].widget.attrs["min"] = -2
        self.fields[i].widget.attrs["max"] = 2
class Meta():
    model = Parings_3
    fields = ["name", "p1", "p2", "p3", "op1", "op2", "op3", "p11", "p12", "p13", "p21", "p22", "p23", "p31", "p32", "p33"]
```

views.py

```
class AddParing3View(View):
def get(self, request):
    form = ParingsForm()
    ctx = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "add_paring_3_form.html", ctx)
def post(self, request):
    form = ParingsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect("parings-view")

class ParingDetails3View(View):
def get(self, request, id):
    player = Parings_3.objects.get(pk=id)
    teamA = [player.p1, player.p2, player.p3]
    teamB = [player.op1, player.op2, player.op3]
    ctx = {
            "teamA": teamA,
            "teamB": teamB,
            "player": player
        }
    return render(request, "paring_details_3.html", ctx)
```

views.py with sessions

```
class AddParing3View(View):
def get(self, request):
     if request.session["teamA3"]:
         teamA = request.session['teamA3']
         form = ParingsForm(initial={
             "p1": teamA[0],
             "p2": teamA[1],
             "p3": teamA[2],
         })
         ctx = {"form": form}
         return render(request, "add_paring_3_form.html", ctx)
     else:
         form = ParingsForm()
         ctx = {"form": form}
         return render(request, "add_paring_3_form.html", ctx)
def post(self, request):
    form = ParingsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect("parings-view")

class ParingDetails3View(View):
def get(self, request, id):
    player = Parings_3.objects.get(pk=id)
    teamA = [player.p1, player.p2, player.p3]
    teamB = [player.op1, player.op2, player.op3]
    request.session['teamA3'] = teamA
    ctx = {
            "teamA": teamA,
            "teamB": teamB,
            "player": player
        }
    return render(request, "paring_details_3.html", ctx)
```

templates

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-color rounded-1 pt-1 pb-1">
    <a class="nav-link btn-color" href="{% url 'add-paring-3' %}">Next</a>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-color rounded-1 pt-1 pb-1">
    <a class="nav-link btn-color" href="{% url 'add-paring-3' %}">New</a>
</button>
```

urls.py

```
path("paring_3/<int:id>/", ParingDetails3View.as_view(), name="paring-details-3"),
path("add_paring_3/", AddParing3View.as_view(), name="add-paring-3"),
```

What I want to do.
User-created Paring and is in ParingsDetailsView.
When the user clicks on the button "New" he will be redirected to view AddParing3View
When the user clicks on the button "Next" he will be redirected to view AddParing3View but with some data, he already submits in form (p1, p2, p3) and fill the new form with this data.

I already try sessions but it "pass" data even I click "new".

Is there an easy way to pass these 3 variables?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to place the "new" link within a form with hidden fields and set the action to `POST`. This way the data is transmitted to the next view invisibly. However, this makes your data vulnerable to modification.

A better way would be to store the data in a cookie (which can be edited as well) or try to get the session working. You could formulate your issues with the session functionality in a new question.